# C++ Libcurl catch verbose data not working properly

Tags: c++, debugging, logging, libcurl, verbose

I want to catch the verbose data which is printed to STDERR in Libcurl (C++). However, I can only point to a file when I want to change `CURLOPT_STDERR`. Of course, I could point to a file, dump the data, read the file and remove the file, but that seems a bad routine?

Besides that, I'm aware of the `CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION` which gives me back bad formatted strings with weird newlines at the end which I can't replace for my logging.

So, how can I catch the clean data (as shown by `STDERR`) from the `CURLOPT_VERBOSE` function?

Comment: You might have something like `fmemopen` to create a `FILE*` from a memory buffer. Then when done you read this memory buffer. Of course, you have to preallocate the buffer, and make it big enough for all data written to it.

Comment: `CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION` gets the exact same logging and is the designed way to catch the verbose info without using a FILE * to direct them to. You must be doing something wrong there...

Comment: @Daniel, indeed, however the strings are formatted with a new line on each line which I can't replace and it breaks my logging logic which makes it overloaded with new lines

Comment: So don't log the newlines? and btw, the verbose text you'd be able to catch from stderr *also* has newlines...

Comment: Well, if you can tell me how not to log the newlines.. it aren't normal \n or \r\n characters